# Как автоматизировать git комиты?

Tags: git, git-commit

Подскажите пример кода, который бы выполнял git commit , git pull и подставлял в коммит текст дату и время. В случае, если обновлений не было, то не создавать коммит. Я хотел бы запускать код с периодичностью, любо подскажите, можно ли в командной строке прописать cron задачу с периодическим запуском?
OS Windows

Answer (score 1):

```
cd "c:\Programs\Test\Git1\first\"    //просто ссылка на папку с репозиторием
set text= "Reserve Copy: %date%   %time% "
git add -A
git commit -m %text%
git push origin master
```

Comment: Надо не забывать пулить перед коммитом-пушем, если хоть кто-то кроме этого скрипта и этой машины может выполнить пуш.

Comment: `git commit -a ...` вместо дополнительной операции `git add -A`.